# Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on tokens, Annotation Name expected

Tags: java, android, syntax, spinner

Multiple markers at this line
    - position cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Cannot refer to a non-final variable items inside an inner class defined       in a different method

```
int multiple=0;
ImageView imageView;
TextView tot_calories;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.items_details);
    Spinner mspin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Integer[] items = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    mspin.setAdapter(adapter);

    TextView name_select=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SelectedName);
    name_select.setText(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);
    imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagedetail);
    UpdateImage(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);
    TextView calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories111);
    calories.setText(constant.food_calories[constant.index]+"");

    tot_calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.caloriestotal);
    mspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new       AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()     {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
            // Your code here
            multiple=items[position]*constant.food_calories[constant.index];
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            return;
        }
    });
    tot_calories.setText(""+multiple);
}
```

Comment: can you post your full class/activity code?

Answer (score 0):

Update this line of code with this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class itemsdetail extends Activity {

int multiple=0;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView tot_calories;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.items_details);
        Spinner mspin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Integer[] items = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        mspin.setAdapter(adapter);

        TextView name_select=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SelectedName);
        name_select.setText(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);
        imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagedetail);
        UpdateImage(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);
        TextView calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories111);
        calories.setText(constant.food_calories[constant.index]+"");

        tot_calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.caloriestotal);
        mspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()     {
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
            // Your code here
            multiple=items[position]*constant.food_calories[constant.index];
          }
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            return;
          } 
        });

        tot_calories.setText(""+multiple);


}   
}
```

Goodluck!

Comment: just after this line public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            return;
            }   <br/>    add <br/>     });

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable multiple inside an inner class defined in a different method @Avani

Comment: is this your full code? if yes thn add a  closing bracket at the end }

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory. You cannot use a non-final variable inside another inner class (the OnItemSelectedListener). You will have to make `multiple` a class member if you want to use it like that.

Comment: declare  variable int multiple = 0; before oncreate() that will solve your problem

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - position cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable items inside an inner class defined in a different

Comment: multiple=items[position]*constant.food_calories[constant.index];